# Openjfx is not installing

Tags: java, openjdk, javafx

I'm using openjdk-8

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.18.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

and i try to install javafx by:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

but it is not installing any of jfxrt.jar, jfxswt.jar etc. in any of openjdk folders and it should according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243982/why-is-javafx-is-not-included-in-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-wily-15-10) post. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've probably figured it out by now, but for anyone else that comes across this, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56166582) worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with openJDK. In case the answer is deleted for some reason, here are the commands he gave - he didn't give any explanation, unfortunately.

```
apt purge openjfx
apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
apt-mark hold openjfx libopenjfx-jni libopenjfx-java
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu! Link only answers are discouraged as they might become obsolete if the link expires in future. May I suggest you to add some details in your post ?

Answer (score 0):

That may not be an ideal solution, but every time when working with JavaFX I use this list of commands:

```
export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-13/lib
```

to add path variable

```
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java
```

to compile program

```
java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX
```

to run program.
Thats simply from [openjfx documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx).