# I can't find JavaFX jar files on after running apt-get install. I don't even think they got installed

Tags: 18.04, java, intellij, javafx

I'm trying to build a JFX app on IntelliJ. I installed JavaFX using the command:

`sudo apt-get install openjfx`

I found somewhere that I am supposed to add `jfxswt.jar` and `jfxrt.jar` to the class path. I ran the `find` command on the root directory but I didn't find either file.

EDIT:
`apt policy openjfx` output:

```
openjfx:
  Installed: 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2
  Candidate: 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 500
        500 http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://jo.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Edit 2:
`dpkg -L openjfx` output:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openjfx
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/copyright
/usr/share/openjfx
/usr/share/openjfx/lib
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.properties
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.base.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.controls.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.fxml.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.media.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.swing.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.web.jar
```

Edit 3:
`ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/` output:

```
accessibility.properties  ext                                jvm.hprof.txt         resources.jar
amd64                     flavormap.properties               logging.properties    rt.jar
calendars.properties      hijrah-config-umalqura.properties  management            security
charsets.jar              images                             management-agent.jar  sound.properties
classlist                 jar.binfmt                         meta-index            swing.properties
cmm                       jce.jar                            net.properties        tzdb.dat
content-types.properties  jexec                              psfontj2d.properties
currency.data             jsse.jar                           psfont.properties.ja
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `apt policy openjfx`

Comment: @Pilot6 I just did

Comment: It is installed. Now run `dpkg -L openjfx`

Comment: And also `ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/`.

Comment: I just ran them both.
Apparently there are javafx files installed but not the jfxswt or jfxrt. Correct me if I'm wrong. Should I add all those jar files to the class path? that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: That's really wierd. It looks like they added a wrong package from 19.10. I tested it on my Ubuntu and really it installs it this way now.

Comment: Huh, it's really weird. It's all very timely for me. Do you have any suggestions?
I tried copying the `jfxrt.jar' and 'jfxswt.jar' from my Windows10 but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how but it finally installed. Here's the link to the answer that I found:

[Openjfx is not installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150860/openjfx-is-not-installing)

The answer is the one by laurenmurphyx64. Here are the commands that I used:

```
apt purge openjfx
apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
apt-mark hold openjfx libopenjfx-jni libopenjfx-java
```